# 315 error when tryin to connect to ADS Database

Tags: delphi, firedac, advantage-database-server, delphi-10.4-sydney, delphi-10.4.2

[image: Firedac error]

This error occurs when i try to connect to a remote ads data dictionary. When researching the error code 315 results only came up for error code 314.

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch issue with the ADS driver.

Comment: Provide FireDAC Environment Report. Most probably, you have an outdated ace32/64.dll

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue by installing aceapi and setting the path of the vendor lib to the syswow path of ace32.dll in FDDrivers.ini